# How did Joi, the holographic companion, know how to find Mariette?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner-2049

**Spoiler Alert!** If you have not watched the recently released movie, Blade Runner 2049, you might want to skip this question.

Policeman Blade-Runner KD36-3.7 (Joe, a.k.a. "Officer K") ...

> buys dinner at a street cafe near a brothel. Three women from the brothel come out to visit him and ask him what he wants. One of the women was Mariette.

Much later in the film ...

> when Joe is alone in his apartment with his holographic companion, Joi, she invites Mariette to visit. Joi wanted to give Joe the experience of sex with her, but could not do that since she was just a holograph, so she invited a woman that she thought Joe would like.

How did she know how to contact or find Mariette?

As a holograph, ...

> she could not leave the apartment to find Mariette on her own. And unless Joe explicitly told Joi about his interaction with the women, she never would have known. To my recollection, Joe never mentioned that interaction to Joi.

It is possible that, ...

> the Wallace company used that information to reprogram Joi because they sometimes tracked Joe's activities and movements.

If you can provide answers from the script or some other official source, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 10):

Joe carried Joi in "stand by mode" in his pocket. That's how corporation tracked him. The order of events is: Joe and Joi have romantic moment in the rain, Joe gets the call, puts Joi on stand by, has meeting with his boss. Goes for a meal later, has a conversation with Mariette. Joi is not being projected but is listening from his pocket all that time. I do not know how was Joi able to contact her; I guess she got Mariette's phone number somehow.

Comment: This is re-iterated by the fact that after K tells Lieutenant Joshi the story about the horse, Joi tells him that he withheld the information about the date on the horse's foot.

Comment: It is also stated that Joi lives both on his home computer and on the emanator he carries with him. At her urging, later in the film, he deletes her presence at his home and just carries her around on the emanator. It can be assumed that, while Joi was still on his home network, she was able to make calls and presumably reached out to Mariette's brothel

Comment: Can Joi listen to Joe's conversations when she is in "stand by mode"? I don't recall any scene that clearly established that ability. If she can, that would allow the Wallace company to do corporate espionage.

Comment: While K is talking with Mariette for the first time, Joi even makes her presence known by sounding her chime (out of jealousy?), and Mariette commented on it. I believe this happens at another point as well. As for how Joi was able to contact her, I agree that she probably simply made a call to the brothel; after all, that's where Mariette told K (while Joi listened) that he could always find her as well.

Answer (score 0):

Given that she can see and hear Mariette, she could do an image/voice search and  then email her -- being a hooker, she probably advertised on the web.